# Windows 10 firewall issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, dhcp

My windows 10 firewall has currently been modified (Not by me), and whenever I need a new DHCP lease.

I had a problem pulling an IP, so I looked at wireshark, and l see both the DHCP Discover from client and DHCP Offer from the server side.

However, no request follows, which told me it was a firewall issue. So I used Avast's firewall and the request went right through and I immediately got my IP.

I checked firewall rules and I see 68 local/67 remote on both outgoing and incoming under svchost.exe app allowed. So, what could be causing this? I have some incoming block statements, but none are to private IP address ranges.

Comment: "I have some incoming block statements, but none are to private IP address ranges." - Have you removed your custom exceptions, in order to actually, rule them out as the cause?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that. No dice.